# AngularJS 1.5 Auth for Unique User Per Tab/Window

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I know there are lots of opinions on this, but I've had an app running for 20 years as a CGI app and have been able to allow different users to be active connecting to different schema on separate tabs/windows. Now I find that I'm in a bind...

On a single LAMP instance, I may have 100 clients (schema), and 1000 users. They are used to being able to work either 2+ users within a client or 2+ users accessing different clients from different browser tabs. It isn't something I can just take away from users after 20+ years.

So far, I'm using basic PHP auth and can see the files changing on the server the second I login via a new tab to the new user (same php file on the server as the previous login). The previous connection info is overwritten with the new info...

Is there anything out there (like an angular module or a php module) that could make this possible without a ton of re-writing?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - use sessionStorage to store string representations of anything related to your User and their currently selected database schema (or whatever is important to keep segregated based on the user logged into your application).

$rootScope is shared across all tabs and as are localStorage and cookies. localStorage even survives closing and reopening of the browser.

sessionStorage has a scope of "per tab/window" and it is destroyed when the tab is closed.

On every call to your REST API, pass the user/database and other needed info to the server. In my case, that means using url args that are hidden using the rewrite module in apache and discarding references to php's $_SESSION. You do not need to pass anything back to the client other than the data you already return.

I created a $rootScope function to convert sessionStorage to an array and another one to handle switching from one "account" to another by updating portions of sessionStorage.

It was a bit of work - 300+ javascript files and 300+ php files to edit using my wonderful vi IDE, but 99% of it was repetitive changes. Once I had a handle on it I was able to edit them all in a couple of days.

It works!!!